# DS-160 transit visa - how do I fill "Address Where You Will Stay in the U.S."

Tags: usa, transit

On my way to Mexico, I'll be having a transit in US (both on the way to Mexico and on the way back). The transit is at Newark, NJ airport and I will not be going outside the airport. So I'm applying for an Alien in Transit (C1) type visa.

In the DS-160 form, it asks me to fill "Address Where You Will Stay in the U.S." Since I'm not actually staying anywhere, how should I fill this required section?

Comment: `3 Brewster Rd, Newark, NJ 07114
Newark Liberty International Airport`, Address or you can put _not applicable_ if it allows you.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

[The DS-160 instructions](http://photos.state.gov/libraries/denmark/29778/pdffiler/DS-160%20FAQ%20web%20version%2005%2028.pdf) say:

> **I am required to give the name of a contact or organization and a
>   phone number, but I am not visiting anyone in the U.S.**
>
> If you do not
>   know anyone personally you may give the name of the hotel, company  or
>   organization you intend to visit. If the question does not apply in
>   your case, you may simply state "does not apply". If you are in
>   transit to a non-U.S. destination, please write "Transit."

Since you're in transit and not leaving the airport, I would write "Transit."

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for, but I could not find it.

Answer (score 6):

[According to the State Department](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/forms/ds-160--online-nonimmigrant-visa-application/frequently-asked-questions.html):

> You may answer a question with “Does Not Apply,” when that question does not apply to you

Answer (score 3):

> 3 Brewster Rd, Newark, NJ 07114 Newark Liberty International Airport

, or you can put *not applicable* if it allows you.

Comment: "N/A" will save a few brush strokes.